# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization at Module.default (post.js:44)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I created a twitter clone with React.js and it is working, but if I try to get the data from the Firebase, I get this error. I get this error in the console. Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization but showing that everything is working fine in the terminal. Please let me know what could be wrong.

**feed.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import db from "../firebase";
import "./feed.css";
import TweetBox from "./TweetBox";
import Post from "./post";

const Feed = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="feed_header">
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>

      <TweetBox />
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post
          displayName={post.displayName}
          userName={post.userName}
          isVerified={post.isVerified}
          text={post.text}
          avatar={post.avatar}
          image={post.image}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Feed;
```

**post.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./post.css";
import VerifiedUserIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VerifiedUser";
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChatBubbleOutline";
import RepeatIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Repeat";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";
import BackupIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Backup";

const Post = ({ displayName, userName, isVerified, text, image, avatar }) => {
  return (
    <div className="post">
      A
      <div className="post__avatar">
        <Avatar src={avatar} />
      </div>
      <div className="post__body">
        <div className="post__header">
          <div className="post__headerText">
            <h3>
              {displayName} {""}
              <span className="post__headerSpecial">
                {isVerified && <VerifiedUserIcon className="post__badge" />}@
                {userName}
              </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div className="post__headerDescription">
            <p>{text}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src={image} alt="" />
        <div className="post__footer">
          <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon fontSize="small" />
          <RepeatIcon fontSize="small" />
          <FavoriteBorderIcon fontSize="small" />
          <BackupIcon fontSize="small" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

**firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "./firebase"

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = firebaseApp.firebase();

export default db;
```

Comment: So the problem is in the code you haven't shown then? In `../firebase`?

Comment: this is the code in my firebase
import firebase from "./firebase"
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = firebaseApp.firebase();

export default db;

Comment: That's your mistake. You're `import firebase from './firebase'` in "firebase.js" is a circular reference. Notice how the path is relative. It should be `import firebase from "firebase"`. Note the difference